# Como aplicar uma regra para um elemento específico?

Tags: css

Preciso deixar uma imagem *blur*, estou aplicando o CSS dessa forma:

```html
<style>
  img {
    -webkit-filter:blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
  }
</style>
```

Porém quando adiciono essa propriedade ela passa para todas imagens do site, como faço para deixar apenas uma foto com esse efeito utilizando CSS?

Comment: Sim, você embaça a imagem conforme a intensidade dada pelo valor dentro do parênteses.

Comment: Ah sim, é que estava *grayscale*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie uma `class` especifica para essa imagem e aplique o estilo desejado na `class` criada, conforme exemplo abaixo. Fazendo isso o estilo definido será aplicado somente à imagem associada à `class` criada.

```css
.imagem1 {
          -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
          filter: grayscale(100%);
         }
```

```html
<img class="imagem1" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/33/b8/69/33b869f90619e81763dbf1fccc896d8d--lion-logo-modern-logo.jpg">
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo Leandro, sua resposta foi bem objetiva e resolveu meu problema, obrigada!!

Answer (score 3):

Utilize um seletor específico para `id` e adicione o `id` na sua imagem.

```
<img id="imagem_especifica">


<style>
  #imagem_especifica {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
  }
</style>
```

O `id` é utilizado para referenciar apenas um objeto. Se for necessário capturar mais de um elemento, mas não todos, aconselho a utilizar `class`.

Veja:

```
<style>


 .imagem_especifica {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
  }
</style>
```

Quando você usa o atributo `id` em um elemento, para referenciá-lo no Css, basta usar o `#` seguido do nome do `id`. A `class` é a mesma coisa, porém você usa o `.` antes do nome.

Comment: Eu acho que se é apenas para UM elemento, eu também iria pelo ID. +1

Answer (score 0):

Voce precisa adicionar uma classe pra imagem que deseja aplicar o filtro

```
 <img src="algumacoisa.png" class="imagemBlur">
```

E no seu css

```
<style>
    .imagemBlur {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
        filter: grayscale(100%);
     }
</style>
```

Desse modo apenas quem tem a classe `imagemBlur` recebe o filtro ;)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode definir uma class à imagem que você deseja aplicar o efeito e depois, no css, dizer qual imagem você quer atingir utilizando o seletor classe. Por exemplo:

**HTML**

```
<img class="filter" src="imagem.jpg" alt="imagem">
```

**CSS**

```
.filter{filter: grayscale(100%)}
```

Veja um pouco mais sobre seletores nesse artigo no [Maujor](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/sintaxetut.php).